# How to insert HTML string into a Microsoft Word document?

Tags: django, templates, ms-word

I have an HTML string captured through user input in a Web application through TextArea.  I would like to populate this HTML string into a Microsoft Word template file.

I can populate normal string into the template file. However, with HTML string, I am not sure, how to do it.

In terms of technology, I am developing a web application in Django.

Comment: Word's "native" format is Word Open XML. A converter is required to incorporate HTML into a Word file. So, in essence, the HTML would need to be converted to valid Word Open XML before being written to the file or it would need to be placed on clipboard and pasted into the Word application or saved to a file and opened in Word (Insert File command).

Comment: Check out Open XML altchunks as a “conversion mechanism” but Word will probably only recognise HTML 4, for example.